# Object Does Not Source Automation Events

Tags: vb6

I am getting "Object Does Not Source Automation Events "

on the following VB 6.0 line

Public WithEvents conn As Connection

Please Help

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you have another class called `Connection`? From another library or from your own code? I assume you want an [ADO connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms807027.aspx), try **forcing** it

```
Public WithEvents conn As ADODB.Connection
```

Comment: I have kinda the same issue. I have written a .NET lib for VB6 project. There are public events with public delegates. It worked before. Now it throes eather that assembly not found, when I make it visible to COM interop it shows Object Does Not Source Automation Events on declaration. Object declared the same:

 `Public WithEvents oDotNetObj As Assembly.Class` 

Not sure where is the problem. It worked before with no COM interop visible set and it was registered with regasm befor and reregistered now.